# Does the size of the GnuPG encrypted file depend on the content of the file?

Tags: gnupg

When I encrypt two different character strings of the same size:

```
echo 'abc' | gpg --yes --encrypt -r loic@dachary.org > /tmp/1
echo 'def' | gpg --yes --encrypt -r loic@dachary.org > /tmp/2
```

I get two encrypted files of the same size:

```
$ ls -l /tmp/[12]
-rw-r--r-- 1 loic loic 592 Feb 26 19:58 /tmp/1
-rw-r--r-- 1 loic loic 592 Feb 26 19:58 /tmp/2
```

Is there any guarantee that this will always be the case ? Or is it possible that the size of the encrypted file varies based on some random factor ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, **the size of the GnuPG encrypted file depends on the content of the file**.

By default GPG will compress the content of encrypted message, which contains a variable part in addition to the payload. Therefore the size of the encrypted message may vary even when the payload does not change.

More importantly, two messages that have the same size but different content are unlikely to compress in the same way, therefore the size of the encrypted message will depend on the content of the payload.

It is however possible to disable compression with the `--compress-algo=none` flag and in this case the size of the encrypted message will be the same regardless of the content of the payload.

Answer (score 0):

In general encryption does not increase the data size and encryption of different data of the same size will produce the same size result.

Note: Most symmetric encryption algorithms such as AES are block based and depending on the mode may require padding the last block so the encrypted data may be up to one block size larger than the unencrypted data.